# F-test with HAC estimate

Tags: r, statistics, autocorrelation

I am calculating a multi-variate OLS regression in R, and I know the residual are autocorrelated. I know I can use Newey-West correction when performing the t-test to check whether one of the coefficient is zero. I can do that using:

```
require(sandwich)
model <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2)
coeftest(model, vcov=NeweyWest(model))
```

where y was the variable to regress and x1 and x2 the predictor. This seems a good approach since my sample size is large.
But what if I want to run an F-test to test whether the coefficient of x1 is 1 and the coefficient of x2 is zero simultaneously? I cannot find a way to do that in R, if I want to account for the autocorrelation of the residuals. For instance, if I use the function `linearHypothesis` in R, it seems that Newey-West cannot be used as an argument of `vcov`. Any suggestion? An alternative would be to do bootstrapping to estimate a confidence ellipse for my point (1,0), but I was hoping to use an F-test if possible. Thank you!

Comment: No data. Code is not reproducible.